# TransformedRegion with piecewise function

Tags: regions, piecewise

Is it possible to use `TransformedRegion` with a `Piecewise` defined function?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

```
V[{x_, y_}] = Piecewise[{{{2 x , y}, x < .5 }, {{.5 x , y}, x >=  .5}}];
Region[
 TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], V]
]
```

**EDIT:** How does `TranformedRegion` transform a region? Why does it not work with simple discontinuous or non-differentiable transformations?

Comment: What happens if you use `Region[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], {Piecewise[{{2 Indexed[#, 1], Indexed[#, 1] < 1/2}, {Indexed[#, 1]/2, Indexed[#, 1] >= 1/2}}], Indexed[#, 2]} &]]`?

Answer (score 3):

The map under consideration is discontinuous on  `Rectangle[]` . I have doubts whether `TransformedRegion` works with such maps. The command

```
Region[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], Function[p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2},
{1/2*p[[1]], p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}]]]
```

crashes the kernel on my comp and the command

```
Region[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], Function[p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2}, 

{3*p[[1]] - 1/2,p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}]]]
```

, where the map is continuous, works well.

Addition. The answer to your question can be done in such a way.

```
r1 = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}],Function[p, {2*p[[1]], p[[2]]}]]
(*Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]*)
r2 = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{1/2, 0},{1, 1}],Function[p, {1/2*p[[1]],p[[2]]}]]
(*Rectangle[{1/4, 0}, {1/2, 1}]*)
RegionUnion[r1, r2]
(*Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already figured out that `TransformedRegion` does not work well with discontinuous functions. I guess what I wanted to ask was why? How does `TransformedRegion` work? I like to understand the reason behind this limitation.

Comment: @Cantor: Your question "How does `TransformedRegion` work? I like to understand the reason behind this limitation" should be addressed to Mathematica developers. As I was informed by Maple developers, the analogous command of Maple finds the image of the boundary of a  transformed region and then fills its interior. If a map is discontinuous, then the image of the boundary as a rule consists of several pieces and the command of Maple does not work. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.